# Concat arrays in ES5 style . Merge arrays into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have to merge chunk of arrays into single array with array of objects in Angularjs.

my input array will be like:

```
[
  [
    {
      "title": "asd",
      "description": "asd"
    },
    {
      "title": "asz",
      "description": "sd"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "ws",
      "description": "sd"
    },
    {
      "title": "re",
      "description": "sd"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "32",
      "description": "xxs"
    },
    {
      "title": "xxc",
      "description": "11"
    }
  ]
]
```

The above input array should be save like array of objects like below

```
[
  {
    "title": "asd",
    "description": "asd"
  },
  {
    "title": "asz",
    "description": "sd"
  },
  {
    "title": "ws",
    "description": "sd"
  },
  {
    "title": "re",
    "description": "sd"
  },
  {
    "title": "32",
    "description": "xxs"
  },
  {
    "title": "xxc",
    "description": "11"
  }
]
```

I did this like below,

```
const input=[[{"title":"asd","description":"asd"},{"title":"asz","description":"sd"}],[{"title":"ws","description":"sd"},{"title":"re","description":"sd"}],[{"title":"32","description":"xxs"},{"title":"xxc","description":"11"}]]
const output = [].concat(...input);
console.log(output);
```

But it is in ES6 i think. Can u help me out with ES5 implementation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Paste your ES6 code into the babel REPL and see if you like the ES5 code it creates :-) --> https://babeljs.io/repl

Comment: you can check various answers here including ES5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `apply` the input array of arrays to `concat`:

```js
var input = [
  [
    {
      "title": "asd",
      "description": "asd"
    },
    {
      "title": "asz",
      "description": "sd"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "ws",
      "description": "sd"
    },
    {
      "title": "re",
      "description": "sd"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "title": "32",
      "description": "xxs"
    },
    {
      "title": "xxc",
      "description": "11"
    }
  ]
];

var result = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], input);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It worked but, Is this ES5 implementation?

Comment: Yes, this is all ES5.

Comment: Thank u, because in production ES6 throwing error.